# Webpack Dev Server и 404 (Not Found)

Tags: webpack, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Здравствуйте, есть проблема:
На сайте с Реактом каждая страница имет свой Энтри Бандл Файл с привязкой на несколько энтри-ИД, собираются бандлы через Вебпак. Хочу подключить "горячую перезагрузку"

```
...
var buildPath = __dirname + '/public/js/bundles';
module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, '/resources/scripts'),
    devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        ...entries...
        campaigns: [
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
            './appjs/campaigns/campaignsEntry.js',
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: buildPath,
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '[name]-bundle-[chunkhash].js' : '[name]-bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        contentBase: buildPath,
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080',
        port: 8080,
        headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
        lazy: false,
        stats: { colors: true }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015-loose', 'react'],
                    plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread', 'transform-class-properties']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    ]
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
...
} else {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
    );
}
```

1) Связь между страницей и сервером есть

2) Сервер следит за обновлениями и создает новый Бандл

3) Но создает его не локально а "виртуально" (на сколько я верно понял инструкцию)

4) Сервер сообщает клиенту о новом Бандле с Хешом

5) Клиент пытается получиться Бандл по адресу, но получет следующую ошибку `raven.js:1074 GET http://localhost:8080/004e386432676c218bd0.hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)`

6) Странная штука - в консоли выдает дважди (а при нормальной работе должно только1 раз на сколько я понимаю) `2 raven.js:80 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...`

7) Если я захожу по адресу `http://localhost:8080/` то ВебпакСервер выдает список всех бандлов, которые были сделаны "сборщиком" Вебпака локально в папке проекта (public/... - сервер на PHP Laravel), ВебпакСервер же туда не вписывает новый Бандл с хешом, но и не дает его по этому адресу

8) Webpack --version = 2.4.1

ВОПРОС: что я делаю не так?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь есть ряд моментов. Давайте по порядку:

1. В чем смысл вот этого параметра `publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'`? Вы итак на 'localhost:8080'. Этот путь подставляется в HTML к ресурсам, в нем есть смысл, если вы хотите цеплять ресурсы из удаленного источника. Здесь же вам достаточно `publicPath: '/'`.
2. `devServer.contentBase` вообще здесь не нужен, он же не отличается от `output.path` (поправьте, если я чего-то не понял). Это может быть одной из причин ваших проблем.
3. Не понятно, где ваш `index.html`. Он должен либо лежать в `output.path`, либо вы должны его генерить каким-либо образом, например через `html-webpack-plugin` и `EJS` шаблон.

В целом, похоже проблема именно в `output.path`. Он должен указывать на ваш "WEB_ROOT", так сказать, а не на место, куда вы складываете бандлы. Путь к бандлам надо указывать в шаблоне имени файла:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'js/bundles/[name]-bundle-[chunkhash].js' : 'js/bundles/[name]-bundle.js'
},

devServer: {
    publicPath: "/",
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot: true
}
```

`index.html`, при этом, как я уже сказал, после сборки должен быть в `/build` директории.

Comment: я не на 'http://localhost:8080/' - если я оставлю "/" то он коннектится к моему серверу если я правильно припоминаю. Адресс сервера строчный и прописан в хостах. Стоит Докер с кучей внутренных портов которые я прописываю наружу. Сервер на PHP с nginx, Node JS, Redis, MariaDB... Вебпак запускает паралельно свой Нод Сервер и общаеться с моей страницей которой я и указываю путь сервера с портом через который он слушает. Запрос из страницы идет на PHP сервер, который выдает ее уже с отрендеренными Реакт Компонентами (тоесть целиком) и Бандлом - никаких index.html

Comment: Подправил `output` и добавил `devServer` в свой ответ. Попробуйте и скажите что выдает `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score -1):

Возможно мой метод будет для вас решением. Нужно запускать webpack-dev-server на внешний ip. Описал в [этой статье](https://blog.zverit.com/frontend/2018/02/12/webpack-dev-server-on-localhost-devices/).

Конфиг будет наподобие этого:

```
devServer: {
   hot: true,
   contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   publicPath: '/',
   host: '192.168.3.186'
   port: 7373,
   proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
       target: '192.168.3.186:8000',
       secure: false,
       changeOrigin: true,
     }
   }
},
```